# Is there a function to get multiple frequency tables within a table in R

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency, percentage

I would like to get multiple frequency tables within a single table.

Here is my data:

```
df<-read.table(text=" group score   night   ticket  book    gender  course
A   Y   1   0   0   Male    M
A   Y   1   0   0   Female  N
A   N   1   1   1   Female  N
A   Y   2   1   1   Female  M
A   Y   2   1   1   Male    N
A   Y   2   0   0   Female  N
A   N   3   1   0   Male    N
B   N   3   1   1   Female  N
B   N   1   0   1   Female  M
B   Y   1   0   1   Female  M

",header=TRUE)
```

and the output would be :

```
    Frequency   Percent
Group       
A   7   70
B   3   30
score       
Y   4   40
N   6   60
night       
1   5   50
2   3   30
3   2   20
book        
0   4   40
1   6   60
gender      
Female  7   70
Male    3   30
course      
M   4   40
N   6   60
```

I have used the following codes:

```
df%>%
group_by( group, score, night, ticket, book, gender, course) %>%
summarise(n = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = n / sum(n)
```

But it did not work for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution would be to apply the `table` function on each column of your frame. Typically `table` returns a named-vector, but you want a more frame-like presentation, so we'll augment that with `as.data.frame.table`.

```r
lst2 <- lapply(df, function(x) {
  out <- as.data.frame.table(table(x))
  out$Pct <- 100*out$Freq/sum(out$Freq)
  out
})
# or code-golf:
# lapply(df, function(x) transform(as.data.frame.table(table(x)), Pct = 100*Freq/sum(Freq)))
lst2
# $group
#   x Freq Pct
# 1 A    7  70
# 2 B    3  30
# $score
#   x Freq Pct
# 1 N    4  40
# 2 Y    6  60
# $night
#   x Freq Pct
# 1 1    5  50
# 2 2    3  30
# 3 3    2  20
# $ticket
#   x Freq Pct
# 1 0    5  50
# 2 1    5  50
# $book
#   x Freq Pct
# 1 0    4  40
# 2 1    6  60
# $gender
#        x Freq Pct
# 1 Female    7  70
# 2   Male    3  30
# $course
#   x Freq Pct
# 1 M    4  40
# 2 N    6  60
```

You can combine all of these elements with something like:

```t
do.call(rbind, c(Map(cbind, nm=names(lst2), lst2), list(make.row.names = FALSE)))
#        nm      x Freq Pct
# 1   group      A    7  70
# 2   group      B    3  30
# 3   score      N    4  40
# 4   score      Y    6  60
# 5   night      1    5  50
# 6   night      2    3  30
# 7   night      3    2  20
# 8  ticket      0    5  50
# 9  ticket      1    5  50
# 10   book      0    4  40
# 11   book      1    6  60
# 12 gender Female    7  70
# 13 gender   Male    3  30
# 14 course      M    4  40
# 15 course      N    6  60
```

*Edited* to remove the row names by default.

Comment: That isn't a column, it's row names. If you capture that output into (say) `df2`, you can do `rownames(df2) <- NULL`. But like I said, this can be safely ignored. Even with that, this frame has only four columns: `nm`, `x`, `Freq`, and `Pct`.

Comment: See my edit. FYI, the row numbers are actually its row names in a sense; just as aesthetic, representative of integer row-indexing but only representative.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tidyverse` would be

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(names(df), ~   df %>% 
                    count(!!rlang::sym(.x)) %>% 
                    mutate(Pct = 100 * n/sum(n)))
```